# Get src of selected image in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

How do you get the full path URL (doesn't need domail) of a selected image within TinyMCE.  My code is listed below and a live example is located at http://jsbin.com/ulUMaYU/1/ (click on image in edit window and then click far right button on toolbar).  My attempt to use `editor.dom.getAttrib(editor.selection.getNode(),'src')` returns the path relative to the parent web browser url.  Yes, I can use `convert_urls : false` but this will be used in a plugin where I don't with to force the user to configure the base tinymce as such.  Thank you

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('image', function(editor, url) {

    editor.addButton('image', {icon: 'image',tooltip: 'getIt',onclick: getIt});

    function getIt() {
        alert('Returns src of selected element relative to parent url: '+editor.dom.getAttrib(editor.selection.getNode(),'src'));
        console.log('testing only',editor,editor.dom,editor.selection,editor.selection.getNode());
    };
});

tinymce.init({
    selector: "#content",
    //convert_urls : false,
    plugins: "image"
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let your browser do the work for you.

You already have access to the image element with `editor.selection.getNode()`. Now all you need to do is check the `src` attribute, which will resolve to an absolute URL via your browser.

Example: http://jsbin.com/ulUMaYU/2

For reference, here's the important stuff:

```
var img = editor.selection.getNode();
alert(img.src);
```